# Como renomear uma pasta adicionado a data atual ao nome

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Tenho uma pasta onde mantenho dados que precisam ser atualizados diariamente. Para não perder o histórico copio esta pasta e colo em outro lugar. Mas, depois de copiar e colar a pasta, preciso renomeá-la com a data atual para não ter pastas com o mesmo nome.

```
Sub faz_backup()
Dim newName As String

CopiarArq "C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Dados MegaWhat\Dados", 
"C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Dados MegaWhat\Histórico"

Data = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
newName = "C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Dados MegaWhat\Histórico\Dados"

Name "C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Dados MegaWhat\Histórico\Dados" 
As newName & Data

End Sub
```

Fiz desta forma. O código copia e cola a pasta, mas aparece um erro dizendo que o arquivo não foi localizado. No entanto, o endereço está correto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está com erro porque a String `Data` retorna o valor: 23/03/2018.
Quando você tenta alterar o nome de uma pasta manualmente e tenta inserir `/`, a seguinte mensagem aparece:

[image: mensagem de erro renomear arquivos caracteres especiais]

Portanto você deve substituir as `/` por algum outro caracter, como por exemplo `-`

Utilizando a função replace, o seguinte código pode ser usado: `DatasemBarra = Replace(Data, "/", "-")`

Então a pasta pode ser renomeada com `Name "C:\MeuCaminho\Desktop\Dados" As newName & DatasemBarra`

#### Código Completo

```
Dim newName As String
Dim FSO As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

Data = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
DatasemBarra = Replace(Data, "/", "-")
newName = "C:\Users\MeuPC\Desktop\Dados"

If FSO.FolderExists(newName) = False Then
    MsgBox newName & " não existe."
    Exit Sub
Else
    Name "C:\Users\MeuPC\Desktop\Dados" As newName & DatasemBarra
End If
```

E uma opção para não utilizar o objeto filesystemobject:

```
Dim newName As String

Data = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
DatasemBarra = Replace(Data, "/", "-")
newName = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Dados"

 If Dir(newName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox newName & " não existe."
    Exit Sub
Else
    Name newName As newName & DatasemBarra
End If
```

Comment: Daniel, bom dia! Fiz as alterações que você disse e tentei executar algumas vezes. As vezes funciona e as vezes aparece o erro: "Erro em tempo de execução '75': Erro de acesso a caminho/arquivo". Algum motivo para isso?

Comment: Em qual linha ocorre o erro?

Comment: Onde renomeia a pasta, na linha do 'name "..." as "...."

Comment: Bom eu não consigo reproduzir este erro, mas você possui alguma restrição de usuário? É um computador de empresa? Pode ser que você não tenha permissão de acesso ou o Caminho está incorreto. Porém se você utilizou o código completo que verifica se há a pasta, o problema provavelmente seria de permissão mesmo.

Comment: Se o usuário não possui acesso para realizar algumas alterações, principalmente no servidor... O departamento de TI poderá te ajudar com as restrições de acesso.

Comment: Entendi! Mas se eu não tivesse permissão de acesso eu não teria problemas para fazer isso manualmente também?

Comment: Veja [este artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/path-file-access-error-error-75) e verifique se a pasta não está como somente leitura. E as permissões do seu usuário da conta. Ou você pode estar inserindo um caminho errado, como por exemplo inserindo a `\` no fim da String de newName

Comment: Daniel, não alterou o resultado.

Comment: Ou você pode estar inserindo um caminho errado, como por exemplo inserindo a barra \ no fim da String de newName. Mas verifique as permissões.

Comment: Daniel, consegui resolver isso! O problema era tempo. O código tentava renomear o arquivo antes de ele aparecer na pasta. Coloquei um comando de Sleep e deu certo.